# Mongodb index, should partialfilters also be included in the index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a query like this:

```
collection.find({
  type: "person",
  image: {
    $exists: true
  }
}, {
  sort: [
    ["age", -1]
  ],
  limit: 9,
)
```

Do I need to include the fields in the index if I already have them filtered?

```
collection.createIndex(
  {type: 1, image: 1, age: -1}, 
  { 
    partialFilterExpression: {
      type: 'person',
      image: {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    background: true
  }
)
```

Or would it already know by the partial filter expression and I'm only querying by what's not fixed?

```
collection.createIndex(
  {age: -1}, 
  { 
    partialFilterExpression: {
      type: 'person',
      image: {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    background: true,
    name: "ageIndex"
  }
)
```

Thinking about it, perhaps the right thing to do is to not index all fields but to use hint to force the db to use the index?

```
collection.find({
  type: "person",
  image: {
    $exists: true
  }
}, {
  sort: [
    ["age", -1]
  ],
  limit: 9,
).hint("ageIndex")
```

Would this actually use index correctly and ignore the other documents in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a collection of **sample documents** being queried, as in the question:

```
{ _id: 1, type: "person", image: "i-1", age: 19, "fld": 12 },
{ _id: 2, type: "person", image: "i-2", age: 22, "fld": 121 },
{ _id: 3, type: "thing", image: "i-99", age: 29, "fld": 1212 },    // 'type' not 'person'
{ _id: 4, type: "person", age: 31, "fld": 12121 },                 // 'image' missing
{ _id: 5, type: "person", image: "i-3", age: 13, "fld": 121212 },
{ _id: 6, type: "person", age: 43, "fld": 1212121 },               // 'image' missing
{ _id: 7, type: "person", image: "i-4", age: 20, "fld": 1 }
```

> Do I need to include the fields in the index if I already have them
>   filtered? Or would it already know by the partial filter expression
>   and I'm only querying by what's not fixed?

Create an **index**:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { type: 1, age: -1 },
  {
     partialFilterExpression: {
       type: 'person',
       image: { $exists: true }
    }
  }
)
```

Note the index fields are on `type` and `age` only. Why? This is explained in the *Index Usage Verification*, below.

The **query**:

```
db.collection.find( { type: "person", image: { $exists: true } } ).sort( { age: -1 } )
```

The **result**:

The query returns the expected filtered documents *and* in the sorted order.

```
{ "_id" : 2, "type" : "person", "image" : "i-2", "age" : 22, "fld" : 121 }
{ "_id" : 7, "type" : "person", "image" : "i-4", "age" : 20, "fld" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "type" : "person", "image" : "i-1", "age" : 19, "fld" : 12 }
{ "_id" : 5, "type" : "person", "image" : "i-3", "age" : 13, "fld" : 121212 }
```

**Index Usage Verification:**

The index usage can be verified by generating the *query plan* using the `explain` method:

```
db.collection.find( { type: "person", image: { $exists: true } } ).sort( { age: -1 } ).explain()
```

The plan output shows the index usage for both the filter *and* sort operations. This is noted as the IXSCAN (indexed scan) and the *absence* of the SORT stage in the plan. This is the correct usage of the index for this query.

In the index definition, the two fields `type` + `age` specify a *compound* index. This is required that the index is applied on the `type` (for filtering) and `age` (for sorting). The field `image` cannot be specified in the index definition as it is *not used with an equality* condition (uses `$exists`); if specified the index will not be used for the following sorted field (from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index)):

> An index can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the
>   index key pattern. To do so, the query must include equality
>   conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys.

The **query plan** (part of it):

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "test.persons",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "type" : {
                                            "$eq" : "person"
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "image" : {
                                            "$exists" : true
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "queryHash" : "25E877F5",
            "planCacheKey" : "C9D745BE",
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                            "image" : {
                                    "$exists" : true
                            }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                    "type" : 1,
                                    "age" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "type_1_age_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "type" : [ ],
                                    "age" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : true,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                    "type" : [
                                            "[\"person\", \"person\"]"
                                    ],
                                    "age" : [
                                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            }, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [MongoDB Partial Index documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#create-a-partial-index) there is no need to include the fields in the index if they're already in partialFilterExpression if performed query within this expression.

The below index will work perfectly for the provided query.

```
collection.createIndex(
  {age: -1}, 
  {partialFilterExpression: { type: 'person', image: { $exists: true }}}
)
```

Query:

```
collection.find({type: "person", image: { $exists: true }}, {sort: [["age", -1]])
```

Even *hint* is not required.

**Important**: If type will be not 'person', or filter for the image will be not provided — the index will not work.

The index will work **ONLY** if the result of the query 100% within the index.

Another example from the documentation:

Index:

```
db.restaurants.createIndex(
   { cuisine: 1, name: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { rating: { $gt: 5 } } }
)
```

Query:

```
db.restaurants.find( { cuisine: "Italian", rating: { $lt: 8 } } )
```

This query will not fall under the above index by reason it includes a rating below 5.